# DML When Component is Loaded

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

### Preface:

I understand that DML is not allowed in getters/setters or constructors. The normal workaround to performing DML on page load is to use the action attribute on the page; however, that's not an option in this case.

### Page:

```
<apex:page controller="testPageController">
    <c:testComponent/>
</apex:page>
```

### Component:

```
<apex:component controller="testComponentController">
    <apex:form rendered="true">
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!init}" name="init"/>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
    init();
    </script>
</apex:component>
```

I have also tried a variant using `$(document).ready(init());` as well as `setTimeout` to no avail.

When I move the `<script>` tag into the `<apex:form>` body, the error goes away; however, that's because the init method never fires.

### Component controller

```
public class testComponentController {
    public void init() {
        update [SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 1];
    }
}
```

I've also tried making the method return a null PageReference to no avail.

### Error

When the page loads up I get the following:

> DML currently not allowed

Knowing that I can't use getters, setters or constructors and apparently this doesn't work either, is there anyway to fire code when the component is loaded in a context that allows DML? Assume I don't have access to the VF page.

### Update

I commented out the call to init and tried to call it from the developer console in chrome and still got the error.

Comment: Did you say (in the main page)...

    <apex:page controller="myController" action="{!pageInitActionHandler}">

... and in the controller:

    public virtual PageReference pageInitActionHandler () {
       ...
    }

...was not workable in this case? That's what we always do.

Comment: Yes this needs to be in the component, not at the page level.

Comment: What's the actual reason for needing to do this? As it stands, I feel like this is an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). There might be better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Load page > update field on a record > send email with that record set as the target object and the updated field should be populated in the email. I need the component to work on ANY VF page and the update and email should happen without any user interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Visualforce Component Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_component.htm) for `<apex:component>` there exists a **Boolean** attribute `allowDML` which enables executing DML within the component and the description for the same is as follows.

> If this attribute is set to "true", you can include DML within the
>   component. The default is "false". Allowing DML can cause side-effects
>   that could be problematic for consumers using the component with
>   partial page updates.
>
> When allowing DML within a component, you should
>   include rerender attributes so the consumer can appropriately refresh
>   their page. In addition, you should detail, in the description of the
>   component, what data is manipulated by the DML so that consumers of
>   the component are aware of potential side-effects.

This should fix your issue.

Comment: The worst part is, I friggin knew this and just forgot :P thanks!

Comment: It happens to all of us. Don't worry..