# No DML_END Issue

Tags: apex, visualforce, error, dml, debug

Yet another "what gives" question.

I have a custom object that is updated upon a button click on a VisualForce Page.

I can see in my debug logs that the object has been updated. But when I refresh the page or query for the object's new data, nothing comes up and there is no DML_END in the debugs. Is it possible that something is happening later down in the process and rolling back the update?

VFP (button click):

```
<apex:page id="CalculatorLinkOnDemand" standardController="FPC_Funding_del__c" extensions="OnlineSalesCalculator" action="{!onlineCalculatorLinkGeneratorOnDemand}">
```

APEX Controller:

```
public PageReference onlineCalculatorLinkGeneratorOnDemand(){
    String funderId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('funderId');
    system.debug('funderID:: ' + funderId);
    callTokenizer(funderId);
    return new pageReference('/' + funderId);
}

@future(callout=true)
public static void callTokenizer(Id funderId){
    //WEBSERVICE CALL OUT AND PARSING TO GET TOKEN
    //excluding for simplicity of question
        system.debug('tokenCredMap:: ' + tokenCredMap);
        tokencred = tokenCredMap.get(funderId);
        if(tokencred != null){
            fpc_funding_del__c f = new fpc_funding_del__c(Id= funderId,CalculatorLink__c= tokencred);
            system.debug('f:: ' +f );
            update f;
        }
}
```

DEBUG LOGS:

ENTIRE LOG: DEFAULT LEVEL:

```
40.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
08:59:55.0 (388318)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|00534000009QnEt|test@test.com| Standard Time|GMT-07:00
08:59:55.0 (426163)|EXECUTION_STARTED
08:59:55.0 (430090)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|FutureHandler - state load
08:59:55.0 (1634138)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|FutureHandler - state load
08:59:55.0 (2482510)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
08:59:55.13 (13681374)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|00534000009QnEe|GMT-07:00
08:59:55.13 (13701877)|EXECUTION_STARTED
08:59:55.13 (13708707)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01pm0000000Kd6Y|OnlineSalesCalculator.callTokenizer(Id)
08:59:55.13 (14873019)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
08:59:55.13 (14928582)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
08:59:55.13 (14966817)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
08:59:55.13 (17101411)|CALLOUT_REQUEST|[79]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://aksdjf;kljads/Token, Method=POST]
08:59:55.13 (398611941)|CALLOUT_RESPONSE|[79]|System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200]
08:59:55.13 (398840960)|USER_DEBUG|[83]|DEBUG|svcAuth LT:::::::::: token 310d4a01-d979-4097-98f4-24a5bU
08:59:55.13 (400536534)|CALLOUT_REQUEST|[97]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://stag;saldkf/enizer/api/ Method=POST]
08:59:55.13 (735402288)|CALLOUT_RESPONSE|[97]|System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200]
08:59:55.13 (735559841)|USER_DEBUG|[99]|DEBUG|tokencred:: [{"Id":"a0Dm0000004bPKnEAM","Token":"lQHYmzhsWURl-YYOzHuW"}]
08:59:55.13 (736938014)|USER_DEBUG|[115]|DEBUG|tokenCredMap:: {null=null, a0Dm0000004bPKnEAM=lQHYmzhsWURl-YYOzHuW}
08:59:55.13 (739060951)|USER_DEBUG|[120]|DEBUG|f:: FPC_Funding_del__c:{Id=a0Dm0000004bPKnEAM, CalculatorLink__c=lQHYmzhsWURl-YYOzHuW}
08:59:55.13 (739118354)|DML_BEGIN|[121]|Op:Update|Type:FPC_Funding_del__c|Rows:1
```

PARTIAL LOG FINEST:

```
08:50:19.10 (546545311)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[117]|tokencred|"NqOGxtx7HQxQn1JC47v5"
08:50:19.10 (546552084)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[118]
08:50:19.10 (546554090)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[119]
08:50:19.10 (546620908)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[119]|Bytes:4
08:50:19.10 (548315088)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[119]|this.Id|"a0Dm0000004bPKnEAM"|0x5a21b5f3
08:50:19.10 (548350149)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[119]|this.CalculatorLink__c|"NqOGxtx7HQxQn1JC47v5"|0x5a21b5f3
08:50:19.10 (548380921)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[119]|f|FPC_Funding_del__c|true|false
08:50:19.10 (548404613)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[119]|f|{"Id":"a0Dm0000004bPKnEAM","CalculatorLink__c":"NqOGxtx7HQxQn1JC47v5"}|0x5a21b5f3
08:50:19.10 (548413541)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[120]
08:50:19.10 (548417576)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[120]|Bytes:4
08:50:19.10 (548443007)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[120]|String.valueOf(Object)
08:50:19.10 (548484592)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[120]|Bytes:82
08:50:19.10 (548499992)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[120]|String.valueOf(Object)
08:50:19.10 (548508994)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[120]|Bytes:86
08:50:19.10 (548518803)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[120]|System.debug(ANY)
08:50:19.10 (548525622)|USER_DEBUG|[120]|DEBUG|f:: FPC_Funding_del__c:{Id=a0Dm0000004bPKnEAM, CalculatorLink__c=NqOGxtx7HQxQn1JC47v5}
08:50:19.10 (548532917)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[120]|System.debug(ANY)
08:50:19.10 (548537731)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[121]
08:50:19.10 (548563191)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[121]|Bytes:8
08:50:19.10 (548580674)|DML_BEGIN| 
[121]|Op:Update|Type:FPC_Funding_del__c|Rows:1
08:50:19.10 (548597219)|LIMIT_USAGE|[121]|DML|1|150
08:50:19.10 (548610448)|LIMIT_USAGE|[121]|DML_ROWS|1|10000
08:50:19.10 (548627080)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
08:50:19.635 (635721081)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING_BEGIN
08:50:19.635 (635721081)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for SOQL operations
08:50:19.635 (635721081)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for SOSL operations
08:50:19.635 (635721081)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|DML operations|
Class.OnlineSalesCalculator.callTokenizer: line 121, column 1: Update: 
FPC_Funding_del__c: executed 0 times in 0 ms
08:50:19.635 (635721081)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|method invocations|
Class.OnlineSalesCalculator.callTokenizer: line 97, column 1: global 
System.HttpResponse send(ANY): executed 1 time in 316 ms
Class.OnlineSalesCalculator.callTokenizer: line 79, column 1: global 
System.HttpResponse send(ANY): executed 1 time in 213 ms
Class.OnlineSalesCalculator.callTokenizer: line 69, column 1: global public 
static Map<String,LinkShorteningAPI__c> getAll(): executed 2 times in 1 ms
External entry point: public static void callTokenizer(Id): executed 0 times in 0 ms
 Class.OnlineSalesCalculator.callTokenizer: line 74, column 1: global void setMethod(String): executed 1 time in 0 ms
 Class.OnlineSalesCalculator.callTokenizer: line 75, column 1: global void setEndpoint(String): executed 1 time in 0 ms
 Class.OnlineSalesCalculator.callTokenizer: line 76, column 1: global void setHeader(String, String): executed 1 time in 0 ms
 Class.OnlineSalesCalculator.callTokenizer: line 77, column 1: global void setBody(String): executed 1 time in 0 ms
 Class.OnlineSalesCalculator.callTokenizer: line 80, column 1: global String getBody(): executed 1 time in 0 ms
 Class.OnlineSalesCalculator.callTokenizer: line 83, column 1: global public static void debug(ANY): executed 1 time in 0 ms
 Class.OnlineSalesCalculator.callTokenizer: line 90, column 1: global void setMethod(String): executed 1 time in 0 ms
 08:50:19.635 (635721081)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING_END
```

As you can see there is no `DML_END`. Why would this be?

Comment: Is this the entire debug or just an excerpt? I ask because if this is the entire log it looks like you have your log levels stripped down pretty heavily so maybe using a different logging level could reveal your answer.

Comment: yes, that's the end of the debug. I have it on the default level but can run it again on finer.

Comment: So it's not the full log, just the end of it, which is fine, I just felt like I had to check :)

Comment: @gNerb I just updated with the full log on "Default" level. Finest was too long to include the entire snippet

Comment: @gNerb Could it have something to do with there being a Future callout? Maybe Async/Sync issue?

Comment: As for your direct question to why there is no DML_END I have no idea. As for the issue with the record not updating, my reccomendation is moving into an isolated org and work on a mimimum viable code sample (using standard object everyone has) and attempt to reproduce the error from scratch using code that we can copy/paste/verify in our own orgs. That will allow us a greater ability to assist you. [Here is an example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225809/dml-when-component-is-loaded) of a question I asked recently where I provided just such an example.

Comment: ah I found the issue. One of my triggers broke because of my updates but my IDE did not display the error. So when it fired off the trigger, all processes stopped.

Comment: Can you post an answer to your own question and outline the error, behavior, and steps you used to troubleshoot so that others with a similar issue can take a look.